# FindClusters and friends run out of memory

Tags: memory, cluster-analysis

I have a 50k lists, each has 1024 real numbers and I wanted to cluster them, but then the kernel crashes from memory pressure:

[image]

[image]

It crashes even with `PerformanceGoal -> "Memory"`. Are there any ways around these issues and to be able to cluster high dimensional vectors?

Comment: You could try using `DimensionReduce` to reduce the complexity of the data. Also, what os/bit length are you running on?

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on since mat and dd are not defined. I might suggest trying a smaller version and making sure you have the inputs are formats correct... i..e, try it on mat[[1;;100]] and see if this runs. Then increase the length.

Comment: Oh, so both dd[[4]] and mat are matrixes of real numbers from -1 to 1 of dimensions = {50k, 1k}